# Add nicEdit to a DIV thats been created by Jquery

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, nicedit

Im trying to implement nicEdit (wysiwyg editor) into an interface im building.

I want to be able to make a DIV editable with nicEdit that is being placed on the page by a jquery ajax call.

If you see this example page on nicEdit http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=4 which gives a nice way to edit DIV's in place.

However the bit of javascript to enable the DIV as editable is as follows:

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
myNicEditor.addInstance('myDiv');
});
```

What I want to be able to do is something like:

```
$("#clickEditIcon").bind('click', function(){
     var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
     myNicEditor.setPanel('nicEdit');
     myNicEditor.addInstance('myDiv');
})
```

From trying this out it doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone have any ideas for getting a DIV editable with nicEdit when clicked or focused on page?

Comment: with a bit of messing about with the above code I got it working.  Id like to explain exactly what I did to fix it but it was just persistance on trying combinations of code. here is rougly what I got to.var nicEdit = new nicEditor();        
        var element = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
        nicEdit.panelInstance(element);